# Prove that: $2pq\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k\leq p^2\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a_k}^{2}+q^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} {b_k}^{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall p,q,a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$ prove that:
>   $$2pq\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k\leq p^2\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a_k}^{2}+q^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} {b_k}^{2}.$$

It is like Cauchy-Scharwz inequality.

When $n=1$ ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$p^2\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a_k}^{2}+q^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} {b_k}^{2}\geq2|pq|\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a_k}^{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} {b_k}^{2}}\geq$$
$$\geq2|pq|\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k\right)^2}=2|pq\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k|\geq2pq\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k.$$
Done!

Answer (score 4):

Use the inequality $2(pa_k)(qb_k) \leq (pa_k)^2+(qb_k)^2$ and sum over $k$.

Comment: (And this inequality is immediate from either the AM-GM inequality, or, more directly, from $x^2+y^2-2xy=(x+y)^2\geq 0$.)

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent with:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (pa_k-qb_k)^2 \ge 0.$$

Comment: Oh, yes. Binom to square.